# Why is past perfect used here?

Tags: tenses, past-perfect

I came across this [God of War video](https://youtu.be/ZjucT-UZzgg?t=74), and heard the following sentence at 1:14:

> Where one journey ended, a new had begun.

Grammatically, what I understand from this is that the "new journey" had begun before the first mentioned journey, which doesn't make sense due to the intrinsic meaning of "new". So i'm confused why they chose to use past perfect here. Now I understand that there might be another event that followed the "new journey", which made it natural to use the past perfect here to describe the timeline, but in that case wouldn't it be more correct to use the past perfect for the first action as well? I.e.:

> Where one journey ***had*** ended, a new had begun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the new journey began, and then the other journey ended, the new one beginning maybe just before. One could begin a new journey before completing a journey one is already on, especially if it's in the same place and around the same time. Anyway, the way it's written, that's what it would mean, which is how you would take it to mean, unless you have some reason to doubt that that's what it means that you haven't provided.